# Does a TableViewCell have to have its own class?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have successfully used custom UITableViewCells using separate classes, but I keep thinking there is an easier way so I have tried the following.  The table builds, but the cells are blank (so presumably my custom cell is not displaying correctly).  Any ideas appreciated.

My files are:

```
@interface RemediesPopUp : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{

    UITableView *remediesDataTable;
    UITableViewCell *remediesTableCell;  // ** custom cell declared here **

    NSArray *remediesArray;

}
```

The table controls are:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    remediesTableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (remediesTableCell == nil) {
        remediesTableCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    return remediesTableCell;

}
```

I dragged a custom cell object into the XIB file pane (so I have the View and a separate custom cell displayed).  I connected the custom cell to File Manager.  To test, I pasted a couple of (static) labels onto the custom cell so I could see if it was loading.

The page and table loads just fine, but the cells are blank (white).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make sure that your custom cell is a custom subclass (subclass of `UITableViewCell`) and has its own nib file (for example, don't integrate it with your table view controller).

In the nib, select the identity inspector and ensure that your cell's class is `CustomCell` (or whatever you called it). Also make sure that under the attributes inspector you set its `Identifier` to "CustomCellIdentifier" or similar.

In your table view data source, your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should contain code similar to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";    // Same as you set in your nib

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id oneCell in nib) {
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)oneCell;
            }
        }
    }

    // Customise the labels etc...

    return cell;
}
```

This ensures that your custom cell is loaded directly from its own nib, allowing you to visually lay out any views or labels. The text for these labels can then be set once the appropriate cell has been dequeued/created.

In your code, your 'custom' cell is just a plain `UITableViewCell`. To customise the cell using interface builder, you need to create your own custom subclass of this.


**EDIT**

For a custom cell that uses only a nib (and *not* a custom subclass), change the above code example to cast the cell to a plain `UITableViewCell`, i.e. change `CustomCell` to `UITableViewCell`. In Interface Builder assign each of your cell's custom views (labels etc) with a unique tag.

With that in place, the code should look something like this:

```
#define MyLabelTag  10    // These should match the tags
#define MyViewTag   11    // assigned in Interface Builder.


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";    // Same as you set in your nib

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id oneCell in nib) {
        if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)oneCell;
        }
    }
}

    // Get references to the views / labels from the tags.
    UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:MyLabelTag];
    UIView *myView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:MyViewTag];

    // Customise the views / labels...
    // ...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: +1, except there is no need to make the cell a custom subclass. Your xib can contain any subviews you like and you can refer to them via tags.

Comment: @jrturton: True, although I personally think it makes things a little clearer if you can refer to, say, a custom cell label via an outlet rather than by an arbitrary tag assigned in IB. Personal preference perhaps.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think jrturton's thoughts are more along the lines that I am thinking.  I believe I don't need a custom subclass.  Could someone expand on this thinking with some suggested code.  Thanks

Comment: @Jeremy: I've added a new example based on jrturton's suggestion of only using the nib and view tags.

Comment: Thanks StuDv.  I'll give that a try.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is put a UIView inside the UITableViewCell, and then put all your labels and other UI stuff in that UIView. If this doesn't work, let me know. I might have another solution.

Comment: Hi Mohabitar.  Please see comments above.  I'm trying not to use subclass, but I'm not sure how to reference objects in the custom cell.  If you have suggested code, it'll be much appreciated.  Thanks.